# want to write header in csv from beanIO field name tag

Tags: java, bean-io

I want to write a header in csv file as my text file does not contain any header so i want to write it from beanIO field name tag

I am having a beanIO with two stream one for reading and another for writing

this is input file....
textInput.txt-
1john dew  BA   xxx
1sam  hart MA   yyy

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();

    factory.load("C:\\Users\\PV5057094\\Demo_workspace\\XlsxMapper\\src\\main\\resources\\Employee.xml");


BeanReader br = factory.createReader("EmployeeInfo",new File("C:\\Temp\\Soc\\textInput.txt"));

    BeanWriter out = factory.createWriter("EmployeeInfoCSV", new File("C:\\Temp\\Soc\\output.csv"));



    Object record;

    while ((record=br.read())!=null) {


        out.write(record);

        System.out.println("Record Written:" + record.toString());

    }

    // in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
   }

}


BeanIO-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">

    <stream name="EmployeeInfo" format="fixedlength">

        <record name="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            class="com.aexp.gmnt.imc.record.submission.Employee">
            <field name="record" length="1" literal="1" rid="true"/>
            <field name="firstName" length="5"/>
            <field name="lastName" length="5"/>
            <field name="title" length="5"/>
            <field name="filler" length="5"/>
        </record>

    </stream>


    <stream name="EmployeeInfoCSV" format="csv">
        <record name="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            class="com.aexp.gmnt.imc.record.submission.Employee">
            <field name="record" length="1" literal="1" rid="true"/>
            <field name="firstName" length="5"/>
            <field name="lastName" length="5"/>
            <field name="title" length="5"/>
            <field name="filler" length="5"/>
        </record>
    </stream>
</beanio>
```

Expected output-

Record,FirstName,LastName,Title,Filler
1,john,dew,BA,xxx
1,sam,hart,MA,yyy

Comment: please add your current output also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a new `record` in your `EmployeeInfoCSV` stream definition that will contain the column names as the default value for the field, e.g.

```
<record name="headers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <field name="recordColumn" default="Record"/>
```

Then you have to tell your `BeanWriter` to first write out a record of "headers" before outputting the rest of the file.

```
out.write("headers", null);
```

You must also change the `length` attribute on the `a` record in your CSV stream to be `maxLength`, otherwise you'll get padding on the output and it would still look like a fixed length format.

Change

```
<field name="firstName" length="5"/>
```

to

```
<field name="firstName" maxLength="5"/>
```

Putting this all together then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
  factory.load("C:\\Users\\PV5057094\\Demo_workspace\\XlsxMapper\\src\\main\\resources\\Employee.xml");

  BeanReader br = factory.createReader("EmployeeInfo",new File("C:\\Temp\\Soc\\textInput.txt"));
  BeanWriter out = factory.createWriter("EmployeeInfoCSV", new File("C:\\Temp\\Soc\\output.csv"));

  // write the column headers to the output file
  out.write("headers", null);

  Object record;
  while ((record=br.read())!=null) {
    out.write(record);
    System.out.println("Record Written:" + record.toString());
  }

  br.close();  // yes, also close the reader
  out.flush();
  out.close();
}
```

And the mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">

  <stream name="EmployeeInfo" format="fixedlength">
      <record name="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
          class="com.aexp.gmnt.imc.record.submission.Employee">
          <field name="record" length="1" literal="1" rid="true"/>
          <field name="firstName" length="5"/>
          <field name="lastName" length="5"/>
          <field name="title" length="5"/>
          <field name="filler" length="5"/>
      </record>
  </stream>

  <stream name="EmployeeInfoCSV" format="csv">
    <record name="headers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <field name="recordColumn" default="Record"/>
      <field name="firstNameColumn" default="FirstName"/>
      <field name="lastNameColumn" default="LastName"/>
      <field name="titleColumn" default="Title"/>
      <field name="fillerColumn" default="Filler"/>
    </record>
    <record name="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
            class="com.aexp.gmnt.imc.record.submission.Employee">
      <field name="record" length="1"/>
      <field name="firstName" maxLength="5"/>
      <field name="lastName" maxLength="5"/>
      <field name="title" maxLength="5"/>
      <field name="filler" maxLength="5"/>
    </record>
  </stream>
</beanio>
```

Comment: one more thing what if i have segment or list in BeanIO that segment i have to print 100 times is this possible to that with this

Comment: It should really be a new question :-) BeanIO can handle it. Is the segment a child of one of your existing records?

Comment: i am having a seagment like <segment name="error" collection="list" minOccurs="0"
     maxOccurs="5" class="com.class">
     <field name="origin_of_error" length="2" />
     <field name="xml_fld_name" length="20" />
     <field name="error_code" length="4"/>
     <field name="value" length="45" />
     <field name="cd" length="4" />
     <field name="cd" length="3" />
    </segment>

Comment: I really think you should ask a new question and explain what you tried, what is the input and expected output like you did with this question. Explain where the segment is involved etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an utils method to dynamically create a Header Record  based on `@Field.name` attribute set at the original Record, it may considered a hack but it's a way better than create a new class or create a XML file just to print the CSV header line IMO.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.beanio.BeanWriter;
import org.beanio.StreamFactory;
import org.beanio.annotation.Field;
import org.beanio.annotation.Record;
import org.beanio.builder.FieldBuilder;
import org.beanio.builder.RecordBuilder;
import org.beanio.builder.StreamBuilder;

public class Headers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String factoryName = "comma delimited csv factory";
    final String headerName = "CarHeader";

    final var builder = new StreamBuilder(factoryName)
        .format("csv")
        .addRecord(Headers.of(Car.class, headerName))
        .addRecord(Car.class)
        ;

    final var factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
    factory.define(builder);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final BeanWriter writer = factory.createWriter(factoryName, new OutputStreamWriter(bout));
    try {
      writer.write(headerName, null);
      writer.write(new Car("Ford Ka", 2016));
      writer.write(new Car("Ford Fusion", 2020));
    } finally {
      writer.close();
    }

    System.out.println(bout.toString());
//    Model,Year
//    Ford Ka,2016
//    Ford Fusion,2020
  }

  public static RecordBuilder of(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
    final RecordBuilder builder = new RecordBuilder(name)
        .order(1);
    if (clazz.getAnnotation(Record.class) == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class must be a BeanIo Record, annotated with @Record");
    }
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field classField : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

      final Field fieldAnnotation = classField.getAnnotation(Field.class);
      if (fieldAnnotation == null) {
        continue;
      }
      builder.addField(
          new FieldBuilder(fieldAnnotation.name())
              .defaultValue(fieldAnnotation.name())
      );

    }
    return builder;
  }

  @Record(order = 2)
  static class Car {

    @Field(name = "Model")
    private String model;

    @Field(name = "Year")
    private Integer year;

    public Car(String model, Integer year) {
      this.model = model;
      this.year = year;
    }

    public String getModel() {
      return model;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
      return year;
    }

    public Car setModel(String model) {
      this.model = model;
      return this;
    }

    public Car setYear(Integer year) {
      this.year = year;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```